# Lista de enlaces permitidos que el input del usuario debe contener

Tags: php

En mi formulario me gustaría que el visitante pueda ingresar en un campo cualquier URL que sea test.com o test2.com (wildcard), por ejemplo test.com/loquesea/39292, como un wildcard.

Tengo lo siguiente en PHP:

```
$allowedsites = array(
'http://test.com/*',
'http://test2.com/*',
);

if(in_array($longlink, $allowedsites)) {
$error = "The URL is in the array!";
}else{
$error = "The URL doesn't exists in the array.";
include ("crear.php");
exit;
}
```

He probado sin el * y con *, no me ha funcionado.
 Es para un acortador de URLs restringido a ciertas **páginas**. ¿Por qué en negrita? Porque no estoy buscando si el input matches con una sola página, sino con más de una. Gracias.

Comment: Utiliza los comentarios para aclarar tu pregunta, asimismo, te invito a realizar el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) en caso tengas más dudas ingresa al [Centro de Ayuda](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help). Recuerda, que puedes [editar tu pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/60792/edit) para ingresar información en caso se necesite.

Answer (score 0):

Pues se me ocurre una función así:

```
echo check('test.com/wtf'); //url válida
echo check('test.com.mx/wtf'); //url válida
echo check('testddd2.com/wtf'); //url no válida

function check($cadena) //funcion que recibe una cadena
{
  if (strpos($cadena, 'test.com') !== false) //strpos() busca coincidencias de una cadena dada con un valor definido. Este te regresa true o false segun sea el caso
  {
      return 'URL válida';
  }

  else
  {
    if (strpos($cadena, 'test.com.mx') !== false) //anidar la función tantas veces como consideres necesario. O hacer un array de "test" y recorrerlo.
    {
      return 'URL válida';
    }

    else
    {
      if (strpos($cadena, 'test2.com') !== false)
      {
        return 'URL válida';
      }

      else
      {
        return 'URL inválida';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

La idea ya la tienes, usa tu ingenio para adecuarlo poco a poco lo que necesitas. Nadie te regalará toda la respuesta a tu programa.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

`in_array` busca una coincidencia exacta, si intentas evaluar variaciones de la cadena necesitas expresiones regulares.

```
$patron = '/^http:[s]?\/\/test[a-z0-9]*\.com\/[a-z]*$/';
$url = 'http://test.com/';

preg_match($patron, $url);
```

`preg_match` te devuelve `1` si la cadena coincide con el patrón o `0` si no lo hace, si pruebas urls como http://test.com/xcadena o http://test2.com te devolvera 1 por ejemplo.